# Tkinter: how to get a string from a top-level entry?

Tags: python, tkinter, toplevel, tkinter-entry

In tkinter, how can I `.get()` the entry from a top level window?

```
def logika(event):
    a=e.get()

def pocetak(event):
    igra=Toplevel(glavni)
    igra.geometry("500x500+710+290")

    e=Entry(igra)
    e.pack()

    GumbIgra=Button(igra,text="Unos")
    GumbIgra.bind("<Button>",func=logika)
    GumbIgra.pack()
    return

glavni=Tk()
glavni.geometry("600x600")
glavni.resizable(True,True)

glavniGumb=Button(glavni,text="Za početak stisni me!",pady=10,padx=15)
glavniGumb.config(font=("Arial",10))
glavniGumb.bind("<Button>",func=pocetak)
glavniGumb.pack()
```

Comment: what is the actual  error or problem? what is the expected output and what are you getting instead?

Answer (score 1):

It seems more like the `logika(event)` function is unable to figure out what is `e`. You will have to pass the object.

So something like this (untested):

```
from tkinter import *
#Creating main window
root = Tk()

def Input_Box():
    # creating a top window
    master_2 = Toplevel(root)

    #Textboxes
    user_name = Entry(master_2)
    user_name.grid(row = 1, column = 2)
    pwd = Entry(master_2)
    pwd.grid(row = 2, column = 2)

    label_un = ttk.Label(master_2, text = "Username")
    label_un.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
    label_pwd = ttk.Label(master_2, text = "Password")
    label_pwd.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

    get_button = Button(master_2, text = "Confirm", command = lambda: getname(user_name))
    get_button.grid(row=3, column = 1)
    master_2.mainloop() 

def getname(user_name):
    input = user_name.get()
    print(input)


call_button = Button(root, text='Enter Usrnm and pwd', command = Input_Box)
call_button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

The `command = lambda: getname(user_name)` passes the `user_name` object that refers to the textbox.
Hope this helps!

Please give us the exact error.

PS: This was for something else but I think this should help.

Comment: So thank you so much for the help ypu gave me for this, but I managed to solve it. it was missing global. That solved everything it was kid of stuppid to even post it here. But anyway thank you for the feedback <3